# SQL Challenge! Validity Dates Splitting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains overlapping validity dates for various ids

| startdate | enddate | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/10/2020 | 8/29/2022 | 1 |
| 10/23/2020 | 6/30/2021 | 2 |
| 10/23/2020 | 6/30/2023 | 3 |

using only SQL (self joins, and lead and lag window functions etc), I would like to split the validity dates and duplicate each entry and assign it to the correct split.  The reason is because we will then be grouping by the start and end dates to create a json list per validity period.

| startdate | enddate | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/10/2020 | 10/23/2020 | 1 |
| 10/23/2020 | 6/30/2021 | 1 |
| 10/23/2020 | 6/30/2021 | 2 |
| 10/23/2020 | 6/30/2021 | 3 |
| 6/30/2021 | 8/29/2022 | 1 |
| 6/30/2021 | 8/29/2022 | 3 |
| 8/29/2022 | 6/30/2023 | 3 |

I ended up just implementing this with a python loop, but I know there must be an sql way of doing it.

This is what I had before giving up.

```
with sorted_sch as( select
       startdate,
       enddate,
       lead(startdate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by startdate) lead_start,
       lead(enddate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by enddate) lead_end,
       lag(startdate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by startdate) lag_start,
       lag(enddate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by enddate) lag_end,
       CASE WHEN lag(startdate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by startdate) is null then startdate
             END imputed_startdate,
       CASE WHEN lead(enddate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by enddate) is null then enddate
            WHEN lag(startdate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by startdate) is not null then least(lag(startdate) over (partition by studioid, trainerid order by startdate),enddate)
            END imputed_enddate
from ts )
select *, coalesce(s3.lag_end, s1.startdate) coalese_start, coalesce(s3.lag_end, s1.startdate) coalese_end,s1.startdate,s1.enddate,least(s1.enddate, s2.startdate) end
from sorted_sch s1
left join sorted_sch s2 on s2.startdate between s1.startdate and s1.enddate## and s1.id != s2.id
left join sorted_sch s3 on s3.enddate between s1.startdate and s1.enddate ##and s1.id != s3.id
```

Comment: With SQL there's always a way, but the way might not be as neat or tidy as in Python.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does it need to be one big SQL statement? Could you use multiple simpler SQL statements along with some Python?

Comment: I don't even understand the question.  What is the logic for splitting one nice clean longer period into shorter periods?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Very strange problem.  You just want to split the existing periods based on all the dates.  So, construct all the dates and then use a join to get each date in-between:

```
with d as (
      select startdate as dte
      from sorted_sch
      union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select enddate
      from sorted_sch
     )
select d.dte as startdate, lead(d.dte, 1, ss.enddate) over (order by d.dte) as enddate,
       ss.id
from sorted_sch ss join
     d
     on d.dte >= ss.startdate and d.dte < ss.enddate
order by startdate;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b23ea1660caacaf230d8f788b25ca1b) is a db<>fiddle.